# How many different passwords of length 7 are there that have at least two different letters appear in succession?

Tags: combinatorics

A password can be created only from lower case letters: a...z.

How many different passwords of length 7 are there that have at least two different letters appear in succession?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "appear in succession"? If there are two different letters, then two different letters appear in succession or am I understanding you wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "appear in succession"? If there are two different letters, then two different letters appear in succession or am I understanding you wrong?

Comment: I think that what the question means - looked it up... is that the two letters are different and appear in a sequence ( at least two of those ). succession = sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by first counting the all possible passwords, that is $26^7$. Next count the number of passwords that don't have two different letters in succession, which are all the passwords that are composed of the same letter. There are 26 such passwords. Thus there is a total of $26^7 - 26$